# Will queries with IP address skip DNS server?

Tags: dns, nameservers

I understand any client applications request queries with domain names will send to DNS server for domain name to IP resolution. But what if the requested queries is IP address only, does it mean the query will not send to DNS server for resolution? I'm wondering if the client applications will make the decision to save a trip to DNS server? Please advise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.if requested is IP address.client will direct connect to that IP.
You can test this by set wrong DNS server,the IP request still works.
IP address request only go through route.domain request will send DNS query then use answer IP to do request.